# Add dynamic items in list<dynamic>

Tags: c#, list

```
List<dynamic> homePageDataList = new List<dynamic>();        
DataTable dt = GetData();        
  homePageDataList.Add(new
{
    Vehicle = dt.Rows[0]["vehName"],
    Lati = dt.Rows[0]["lat"],
    Long = dt.Rows[0]["lngt"],


    if(dt.Rows[0]["userType"].ToString()=="2")
    {
        TripStatus =  dt.Rows[0]["delstatus"].ToString();                                        
    }                                
     Date = dt.Rows[0]["dtTime"],
});
```

Here I want to add `TripStats` only with the condition of if `userType==2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using an [expando](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) object if you want to add properties dynamically.

```
List<dynamic> homePageDataList = new List<dynamic>();        
DataTable dt = GetData();  

dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
            expando.Vehicle = dt.Rows[0]["vehName"];
            expando.Lati =dt.Rows[0]["Lati "];
            expando.Long = dt.Rows[0]["Long "];
            expando.Date = dt.Rows[0]["Date "];

 if(dt.Rows[0]["userType"].ToString()=="2")
    {
        expando.TripStatus =  dt.Rows[0]["delstatus"].ToString();                                        
    }    

homePageDataList.Add(expando);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Ternary Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) (inline if-statement) like below:

```
TripStatus = dt.Rows[0]["userType"].ToString()=="2" ? dt.Rows[0]["delstatus"].ToString() : "",
```

Comment: Thanks for you valuable answer.
But I want show TripStatus only if usertype==2. Other wise I don't want TripStatus.

Comment: @RakeshTailor Well you can set it to **null** instead of empty string if usertype !=2.